# Partition of a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with millions of rows in it and it is taking long time to retrieve data from it while querying it. I tried to partition it based on the date. I have the following table with column names as

```
ERROR_IND
FEED_ID
QUEUE_ID
FEED_DT_TM-- Date datatype.
```

I tried using the redefinition package available in Oracle to partition it, but did not work . Please advise me an efficient way of partitioning of a table.

Comment: How do you mean did not work? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: maybe read the Oracle docs first ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm ).  How you access the data will largely determine your partitioning approach (range partitioned would be my guess from what your posted).

Answer (score 3):

Tables can't be redefined if:

- they have materialized views or materialized view logs on them
- they contain BFILE, LONG RAW or LONG columns
- they belong to SYS or SYSTEM
- the database is in NOLOGGING mode
- they are temporary or clustered

Calling `DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE` will confirm if your table is suitable.

Follow this [link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/PartitioningAnExistingTable.php) for a good guide on how to partition an existing table with `DBMS_REDEFINITION`.